# Scala - second-generation inheritance of a common trait

Tags: class, scala, inheritance, traits

If I have the following code in Scala:

```
trait A {
  var yo = 10
  def get = yo
}

trait B extends A { /* makes use of A.get */ }
trait C extends A { /* makes use of A.get */ }

trait D extends B with C { /* makes use of A.get */ }

class E extends D { /* makes use of A.get */ }
```

How will the compiler resolute the dependencies? In other words, will it understand that the A-trait related part of trait D and object E, inherited from the two different traits B and C has to be treated as a single thing, and not duplicated for every case of inheritance? In any way, what will the thoughts of the compiler look like in that situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.6) chapter of Programming in Scala, as suggested by tenshi, we have the following example:

```
class Animal 
trait Furry extends Animal
trait HasLegs extends Animal
trait FourLegged extends HasLegs
class Cat extends Animal with Furry with FourLegged
```

Which derives into the following pipeline:

```
Cat -> FourLegged -> HasLegs -> Furry -> Animal
```

So the one on the right has priority, but his ancestors, as long as they are not common ancestors of others on the pipeline, also have priority. This is why `HasLegs` comes before `Furry`.

Finally, here is the answer for your particular example:

```
E -> D -> C -> B -> A
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe, that this chapter of [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/) can help you in understanding of trait linearization process:

[Programming in Scala - 12.6 Why not multiple inheritance?](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.6)

Comment: So, what seem to be the same variable here, will be linearized by shadowing that variable of the type, positioned the leftmost in the inheritance instruction by one that is positioned more to the right?